# String becomes null outside of Anonymous Inner Class

Tags: java, android, anonymous-inner-class

I am retrieving the `LastKnowlocation` with google's `FusedLocationClient` and storing  `userLocality` and `userCountry` as two strings in `OnsuccesListener` anonymous inner class.

In the code below: the text set is correct in the `locationProvidedTextView`(therefore  `userLocality` and `userCountry` get some values) but when I try to print  the string values outside of the inner class they somehow both become `null`.

It might be a stupid question, but **what am I doing wrong**? I need to use those values in another `OnclickListener` method.

Code snippet:

```
    // GlOBAL VARIABLES
   ....
   private  String userCountry;
   private  String userLocality;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ....
 mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        try {
                            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder
        .getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                     userLocality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                     userCountry = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

                                    locationProvidedTextView.setText("Your address: " + userLocality + ", " + userCountry);

                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
 // HERE BOTH STRINGS BECOME NULL
    System.out.println("ADDRESS1 ======= " + userLocality);
    System.out.println("ADDRESS2 ======= " + userCountry);
          ....
   }
```

Comment: In fact you seem to be printing the values, before the listener has had a chance to get called, even though you declared it first .

Comment: `getLastLocation()` seems to be an asynchronous call. Add a couple of breakpoints and you will see how that works

Comment: `OnSuccess(Location location)` will be getting called asynchronously. Your values are `null` because the values will be null before the values is being assigned into `onSuccess()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obtaining location will take some time. As per your code you are printing immediately `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener`

Your listener won't get called immediately. So you won't get any value in those strings.

A better way of implementation is, do all the location related thing in another class, not in onCreate. Then use `interface` to get the result once you got it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you did not build any mechanism for retrieving the values. In other words your `onCreate` looks like this right now:

```
onCreate{
// set listener
// print stuff out
}
```

The values are getting set after the listener gets called, but at that point you are already done with the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thank you.The explanation is correct yet it provides no solution

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

I don't know your code however it seems that addOnSuccessListener is an asynchronous mechanism.

So you want to display outside the asynchronous part the value which has not been set.

In other words you try to display a value which has not been set.

To test this you can put:
Inside the addOnSuccessListener a:

```
System.out.println("User locality found");
```

You will see that message is probably comming after the

```
System.out.println("ADDRESS1 ======= " + userLocality);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder
    .getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                 userLocality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                 userCountry = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

                                locationProvidedTextView.setText("Your address: " + userLocality + ", " + userCountry);

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I guess this method set data to userLocality and userCountry each time when it gets the cordinates based on the GPS accurately but when GPS is disable or network is not strong it can give false reading which may result in getting null String variables here you should try changing the provider and the accuracy of the network or gps provider this might help.